# If I drop some things from a distance how do I know which one has the deepest or shallower depression?

Tags: energy, kinetic-theory

Suppose I drop something from 200 cm and another thing from 20 cm. Which will cause a deeper depression?

Comment: See the homework help guidelines [here](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange)

Comment: I've done ncert myself as I've studied in CBSE but these aren't really the type of questions which this site is looking for. If you want to post a problem which you want help on, then show what you've tried already and then people can give you specific help

Comment: Secondly, this activity you're supposed to do yourself. If you have a doubt on something about what is done in it, then there are a lot of people on this site who are more than happy to help you but as of right now your question is just the question from book. I'm not sure what you are expecting.

Comment: Ok thanks will mind these things when asking questions from next time.

Comment: You are free to edit the current question and make it better. If not, you can delete this one and post another one which you have thought out more.

Comment: Great, now what's your question?

Comment: Much better, but now tell what kind of you things you are dropping? where are you dropping them into?

If you simply drop something then it'll fall onto the ground.

Comment: Whatever object you drop they'll lay on ground after falling. So, there is no question of deeper or shallower here. Also, try to change your title so that a person who is coming to click the question know's what it is about it before they read the whole thing.

Comment: I think you may want to add that you are talking about depressions in sand

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all you must distinguish between those two bodies and clarify their properties. The answer which I have given is based on the fact that both are similar objects and are being dropped on **sand** (since it forms observable depressions).

Okay, Since both are similar objects , the one at a greater height will gain more kinetic energy and thus will have more **momentum (or say velocity)** than the one dropped from a lower height . This is because the one at a greater height has more gravitational potential energy with the earth.

Now from Newton's second law, we know that

$$F_{net} = \frac{dP}{dt}$$ or  $$F_{net} = ma$$

Now since bodies are similar , both experience the same amount of force. So the one with lesser momentum(or velocity) will stop earlier than the one with higher momentum (or velocity) and thus the ball dropped from a greater height makes a deeper depression in the **sand**.

**Note** : You can also use these concepts for bodies of different mass but in that case do remember that even if the force of the sand on them is same , they will have different acceleration and so depending on their initial speed before striking the sand , they will make different depressions.

Hope it helps ☺️.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I was waiting for this.

Comment: @Dingus45191 was that helpful ?

Comment: Thanks  , it helped me a lot

Comment: @Dingus45191 glad to know this. If you really liked the answer then  you may accept it.